# I accidentally started a new git init on an existing git project, what do I need to get it back to normal?

Tags: git, github, version-control

And after that I deleted the git init with `rm -rf .git` and started a new one with `git init`, I messed my project? I want my older git configuration on my project, what can I do now?

Comment: The original question in the header is a good and relevant question. The additional question regarding `rm -rf` is a different question and should be asked separately.

Comment: I did “git exit” instead of just “exit”, but since I had auto correct set up in system config file, it interpret it as “git init”. I was tensed seeing that command executed but first thing I did was ‘git log” and that showed me all the commits, so as Greg said, it was benign. Second thing I did was remove that auto correct setting from system config. Lesson learned, never start something you don’t know how to stop :-). P.S: apparently q or :q helps quit. but I still like the idea of me entering command and pressing enter key than auto correct turning a exit into init :-).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Running `git init` on an existing project does not do anything bad (it just copies any new templates), as documented in the [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init):

> Running *git init* in an existing repository is safe. It will not overwrite things that are already there. The primary reason for rerunning *git init* is to pick up newly added templates (or to move the repository to another place if --separate-git-dir is given).

By then running `rm -rf .git`, you deleted your own repository (I can't imagine why you expected that command to do anything else). Hope you have backups.

Comment: This does not answer his main question which is how do you restore the project.

Comment: @B-TronoftheAutobots True, but the question assumes that the repo *can* be restored, and because the OP also did `rm -rf .git`, it cannot, of course. The question is flawed, but this answer provides everything one needs to know about the situation. I accidentally did a `git init` in the wrong folder but did not delete `.git`, I found this answer and it was helpful.