# New git init broke connection to the files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab

I was trying to push my code (ruby on rails) stored in GitLab to production. As it didn't work, I tried to check git repository and accidentally created a new one through `project/repo$ git init`.
After that I got a message about *Initializing a new repository*.
According to other solutions for accident `git init`, it wouldn't be a problem if I initialized a new repository in already existing one, but in this case I would get the *Reinitializing existing repository* message, which I didn't get. So should I just delete the repository via `rm -rf .git`? According to this [I accidentally started a new git init on an existing git project, what do I need to get it back to normal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632376/i-accidentally-started-a-new-git-init-on-an-existing-git-project-what-do-i-need), it will do me no good, or it might be different situation?

I have very little technical knowledge, so if you could explain "for dummies" that would be great!

**Update**: I deleted the repository and everything works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the full message about "initializing a new repository"? In short, yes all git related files are stored in the `.git` directory so if you delete it you can start fresh. That sounds like a good idea considering that you won't loose anything yet.

Note that `git init` only sets up the repo to commit. *You still need to make an initial commit* in order to push to your remote on GitLab. You do this via git's `commit` command.

Comment: As I can recall, the message was about initializing an empty repository. What I'm afraid of is that if I delete this directory, am I going to delete all the previous information? Because after I added 'origin', I can see the branches through `git branches -r`, but the deployment can't. I tried commiting, but it didn't help. I wonder, how is it possible that it worked before without calling `git init` in the first place.

Comment: Do you have a commit history? (What is the output of `git log`?) If not, there's nothing to loose. I'm no longer clear on what you are trying to do. Are you trying to push an existing project with a commit history to Gitlab or are you trying to "git"-ify an existing project without a commit history?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the exact command you ran and the exact error message that it produced.

Comment: Okay, I found that commiting was wrong and now made it properly, so the log give me only this `commit 52471d222d2437d60272afaac3ab8b81f9a58af6
Author: XXX <XXX@mail.de>
Date:   Mon Feb 29 02:34:04 2016 +0100

    initial commit`. If I understood you right, this means that deleting of this git is safe? And I can just use `rm -rf .git`?

Comment: If you remove the .git directory, you will loose the project history and the project will be permanently set in whatever state it is currently in. If you don't have any history, then there's no loss to starting over from a clean slate. If you do have history, then there a loss. To determine whether or not you have a history, run `git log`.

Comment: I see that nothing was commited here on this git, but I also know that lots of things were commited to the repository which I provide in the link `git remote add origin git@....link.git`. I am not sure how exactly they were commited there, but I know that they used git gui to send data to GitLab from their local developing environments. That is why the question is: will the removal of my git cause the removal of the previous changes (not seen in my log)?

Comment: So you are trying to contribute to an existing project then push to production? Please describe the production environment.